# What's the best way to manipulate excel data in Python

Tags: python, excel

I want to import an excel spread sheet into Python so I can then manipulate the data, how do I got about this?

Comment: When I had to do this I had to create a .csv file from the spreadsheet and then learn to use the csv import. As an example, I had questions such as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20981936/python-dictread-of-csv-file-with-nul-bytes-in-data The question as you ask it is too broad.

Comment: I'd probably read in the csv as a pandas dataframe, using ipython / jupyter, and go from there. A good place to start: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/tutorials.html